# Import XML via VBA, access attribute

Tags: xml, vba, nodes

XML sample:

```html
<User id='user1'>
 <Attribute name='firstname' value='Testname'/>
 <Attribute name='lastname' value='Testname'/>
 <Attribute name='id' value='userid'/>
</User>
<User id='user2'>
 <Attribute name='firstname' value='Testname'/>
 <Attribute name='lastname' value='Testname'/>
 <Attribute name='id' value='userid'/>
</User>
```

I want to extract the firstname, lastname, id of the current user via VBA.

VBA snippet:

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xmlSelection As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.Load strUrl

Set xmlSelection = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("PATH TO XML")

For Each xmlElement In xmlSelection
    Debug.Print xmlElement.getAttribute("name")
    >>> how do I debug print the attributes firstname, lastname, name?! I need the values <<<

Next xmlElement
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*You could not directly print object,but could print its child text string
 instead.*

*Seems your XML is not an complete one but part of it,right?I only use one node as root node for the example.*

```
Set Nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//User")
For Each Node In Nodes
    For i = 0 To Node.childNodes.Length - 1
        ' Print Attribute Name
        Debug.Print Node.childNodes(i).Attributes(0).Text
        ' Print Attribute Value
        Debug.Print Node.childNodes(i).Attributes(1).Text
    Next i
Next Node
```